# Python report bbox pyquery within PDF when multiple LTTextLineHorizontal

Tags: pyquery

I have a PDF file on which I want to report a specific "Contact Name:" text bbox set of coordinates.

I am using pyquery with a kind of statement:
pdf.pq('LTTextLineHorizontal:contains("Contact Name:")')
Then, I select the coordinates with
float(ContactNameLocation.attr('y0'))
However, there is multiple "LTTextLineHorizontal" at the same hierarchy level where the text is located.

Contact Name:

Only the first bbox set of coordinates is reported when the text has its bbox at the end.
How shall I do to get the last bbox coordinates?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Example of ODF converterd to XML:
" <LTTextLineHorizontal y0="3" y1="3" x0="6" x1="3"  width="..." height="..." bbox="[6, 3, 3, 3]" > </LTTextLineHorizontal>
<LTTextLineHorizontal y0="4" y1="5" x0="7" x1="8" width="..." height=".." bbox="[7, 4, 8, 5]" word_margin="0.1">Contact Name: </LTTextLineHorizontal>"

pdf.pq('LTTextLineHorizontal:contains("Contact Name:")') returns 
bbox="[62.88, 372.072, 306.24, 388.304]" instead of box="[68.16, 364.152, 125.761, 372.152]"
How can I get the second bbox instead of the first one?